# Why does my css sprite look like an old movie?

Tags: css, sprite

I can't figure out why my sprite is animating like an old film instead of changing background-position from one spot to the next. It transitions in a smooth scroll from left to right, which makes sense since I ask the position to change from left to right, but shouldn't it jump from one image to the next since I used steps()? Please help figure out what I did wrong:

```
#sprite {
background: url('img/example.png') no-repeat -4px -5px;
width: 43px;
height: 82px;

  -webkit-animation: dance .5s steps(4) infinite;
        animation: dance .5s steps(4) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes dance {
0% { background: url('img/example.png') no-repeat -4px -5px; width: 43px; height: 82px; }
33% { background: url('img/example.png') no-repeat -52px -6px; width: 43px; height: 81px;}
66% { background: url('img/example.png') no-repeat -100px -7px; width: 43px; height: 80px;}
100% { background: url('img/example.png') no-repeat -148px -6px; width: 43px; height: 81px;}
}

@keyframes dance {
0% { background: url('img/example.png') no-repeat -4px -5px; width: 43px; height: 82px; }
33% { background: url('img/example.png') no-repeat -52px -6px; width: 43px; height: 81px;}
66% { background: url('img/example.png') no-repeat -100px -7px; width: 43px; height: 80px;}
100% { background: url('img/example.png') no-repeat -148px -6px; width: 43px; height: 81px;}
}
```

I'm really having trouble figuring it out and I'm pretty bad at explaining, so I thought maybe I could make a JSFiddle to show the difference of how it's animating in my version vs [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/).

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew2KJ/)

I would really appreciate any help you can offer. Please let me know if I can provide any additional info to help figure this out.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean. Please clarify. "Like an old movie" doesn't tell me much.

Comment: @David Sorry, it transitions by scrolling left to right. Which I understand I'm asking the program to move from a left position to a right position, but shouldn't it jump from one image to the next since I used steps()?

Comment: Take a look at [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/light/). It uses steps and `from/to` to do its animation.

Comment: Thank you, I used that as my base actually, but adjusted using the position css from [Sprite Cow](http://www.spritecow.com/). Just tried to change to a from/to but still has that odd sliding technique, where as in the example it transitions from one image to the next using steps(). Is there a css animation course/video I should review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timing function (in this case steps) , when you set an animation with multiple keyframes, applies to the transition between one keyframe and the next.

So, even if it seems strange, the CSS should be

```
#ryu {
    -webkit-animation: dance 8s steps(1) infinite;
    animation: dance 8s steps(1) infinite;
}
```

that is, with only one step

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ew2KJ/1/)

Comment: That is awesome, it's working!! Thank you for explaining that to me, it makes sense now :)